# compare multiple columns to get rows that are different in two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frames

```
df1 
172
72A
12(1)
192
182


   

df2
172
72A
12(2)
122
88
```

I want to compare both the data frames, and   want to find rows in df1 that are not found in df2,
then the predicted rows have to write in a new column, no need to consider the value inside the bracket.

```
expected result
 122
 88
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.isin`; however, the parenthesis adds a little bit of logic, so you can `split` on parenthesis and take `.str[0]` to return the first part of it. The column names are literally `df1` and `df2` to avoid confusion. Switch these to whatever your actual headers are:

```
df2[~df2['df2'].str.split('(').str[0].isin(df1['df1'].str.split('(').str[0])]

    df2
3   122
4    88
```

`~` returns the inverse rows of the output of `isin` that would be returned without using `~`.